# SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

How much space is required by SQL Server 2008

Comment: Can you be more elablorate as to what are your requirements?

Answer (score 2):

MSSQL 2008

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(SQL.100).aspx

280 MB

MSSQL 2008 R2

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx

711 MB

Answer (score 0):

You will need a minimum of 711MB for the core libraries. Additional space is needed for additional features. See the [MSDN page on SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx#HardDiskSpace) for specific numbers. At this stage you do not have any space required for the actual database... That depends on what you wish to store.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx#HardDiskSpace